# Iptables, masquerade and snat

Tags: linux, iptables, firewall, cloud, google

I have this situation:

My LAN; 172.18.0.0/24
I need to masquerade all traffic directed to 10.201.3.170/29 with the 10.201.3.190/29.

```
--my ip source: 172.18.0.2 
--destination to 10.201.3.171
--masquerade IP from 172.18.0.2 to 10.201.3.192
--receive response
```

all other connection need to work normally, without any changes.

Anyone can help me?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself already? What? Edit your question to add this info

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to rephrase your question. All traffic destined to the host 10.201.3.170 must be NATted to 10.201.3.190 as it leaves the firewall. If this is correct, then it wont work. You chose a subnet of /29. Therefore hosts 10.201.3.170 and 10.201.3.190 do not belong to the same subnet. A subnet of /27 can accommodate both hosts.

If you look closely, 10.201.3.192/29 is an invalid IP address and cannot be assigned to an interface.